# EMF & Magnetic force at the same time?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

A conductor is placed in a magnetic field, current starts to flow, and the wire experiences the Lorentz force of $x$ Newtons. However, what confuses me is that $x$ is a **value** that is calculated from $F = IL \times B$. If $-EMF$ is induced due to the change in exterior magnetic field(due to the current now flowing in the conductor), shouldn't $I$ be reduced thus total $F$ (which is $x$) should be less than initially calculated?

Also,if two wires have current flowing within them, as they initially "start" when current "beings" to flow, shouldn't there be $EMF$ induced?

And what occurs first? The magnetic force or $EMF$ or do they occur simultaneously?

I myself am confused about this notion, so this might sound a bit absurd please do state if it is unclear. I will review this and try to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: Recall that the magnetic force is always perpendicular to the direction of (charge motion) or (current flow). As for simultaneity, how did you deal with friction and gravity acting on a block on a ramp? That is also two forces acting at the same time and in different directions.